# Cursor following text appears taller than the text

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea to input text, if I type some words the cursor following the text appears taller than it should be (as depicted below). Why is it showing that way? Can it be as tall as the words with their font size as 38px?

The code snippet:

```
<textarea name="quotes" cols="40" rows="10"   placeholder="  What`s your quotes? " style="height:100px;width:99%;overflow:auto;border: 1px solid silver;font-size:38px" keynav:shortcut="10"></textarea>
```

An illustration:

[image]

The browser I am using is Chrome.

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: What browser/OS? Why the jQuery tag?

Comment: Are you setting line-height somewhere?

Comment: @j08691 Google chrome,  Jquery tag because may be this question problem is related to some jquery/javascript technique

Comment: "this question problem is related to some jquery/javascript technique" How so?

Comment: @j08691 I don't know, that's why i said "may be"!

Comment: Someone has did vote down, why?

Comment: So you don't have any existing JavaScript that might be causing this correct?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cdsn2/ -- The line height looks fine to me considering how big the font is.

Comment: @tymeJV  Why Ashutosh code is not working, your jsfiddle works very fine.

Comment: @tymeJV Then what should i do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question ('Why does the blinking cursor appear larger than the text?') is that it's an illusion.  The cursor actually is the height of the full height of the line.  Remember that the bottom of a g, j, p, q, or y is also part of the line.  So, it might **appear** that the blinking cursor is taller than the line, but it really isn't.

Comment: So what should i do for this, to prevent the larger cursor.  This is not looking good

Comment: @Ashutosh, choose a smaller font?  Then it won't be so noticeable.  However, this is correct behaviour, and I'm afraid there's not much you can (or should want to) do about it.

Comment: I want font to be larger. Here http://jsfiddle.net/Cdsn2/ its working fine . But only my page is having such problem...why

Comment: @Ashutosh, the jsfiddle has a cursor that is 38px high. In which sense is your page different? Is it because the font family is different, with letters smaller in height?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably solved cause are from 3 years from now, but reading the comments saying that were an ilusion problem(cause cursor was same size of the line, i solved my problem using :

```
line-height: 27px;
```

in my input field.

Maybe can help someone in future :D

Answer (score 0):

The font matters in this issue, and please try editing in these three text areas:

```html
<textarea name="quotes" cols="40" rows="1"   placeholder="What`s your quotes? " style="height:60px;width:99%;overflow:auto;border: 1px solid silver;font-size:38px" keynav:shortcut="10">font 1</textarea>
<textarea name="quotes" cols="40" rows="1"   placeholder="What`s your quotes? " style="height:60px;width:99%;overflow:auto;border: 1px solid silver;font-size:38px;font-family:fantasy" keynav:shortcut="10">ffffff 2</textarea>
<textarea name="quotes" cols="40" rows="1"   placeholder="What`s your quotes? " style="height:60px;width:99%;overflow:auto;border: 1px solid silver;font-size:38px;font-family:cursive" keynav:shortcut="10">gggggg 3</textarea>
```

You'll see that the cursor in the first one appears normal, the second and the third taller exceeding downward and upward respectively. Here is the pen on Codepen: https://codepen.io/lerner-zhang/pen/ExregOd